# React Native: keep keyboard open on long press

Tags: react-native, keyboard

I want to keep keyboard open when user makes long press inside scrollView. I already have `keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'` to avoid closing on simple taps but has no idea how to make keyboard ignore long presses. I've already tried `event.preventDefault()` & `event.stopPropagation()` inside long press handler but have no results.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: @TomášPetrovčín Unfortunately no(